# How can I send file to list - .net core web api - postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data, iformfile

I'm trying to send a `file` from a `postman` to a `web api`, method on `web api` is expecting a list of type which contains *doc type, file and folder name..* posted below:

**Web api method:**

```
[HttpPost("post-images")]
public async Task<IList<RepositoryItem>> PostAnImages (IList<PostRepoRequest> request)
{
    // rest of the code 
}
```

**PostRepoRequest class:**

```
public class PostRepoRequest
{
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Folder { get; set; }
}
```

As it's possible to notice I've never received a file, **its allways null**,
I've tried also setting a header content-type as `multipart/form-data` but that didn't worked aswell..

What might be the trick here?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: You should use multipart/form-data but accept and process it differently on the server side.  You can check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

Comment: @OguzOzgul I've tried adding content-type as I said in post but that didn't helped I've received File as null... maybe because it's part of the list ?.. hmmm not sure

Comment: I think you need to use [FromForm]IFormFile (attribute) as parameter in your backend method

Comment: Did you check the link I've provided? Changing the content-type only is not enough. multipart/form-data has a format which uses boundaries to separate the parts. Please read the documentation. It must be handled differently.

Comment: You just need to take in a List<IFormFile> because all the other info is there already.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro can you explain it bit further?

Comment: The other fields are document type and folder... But IFormFile already contains information about the file being uploaded... so you dont need those fields... All you need is one paramter List<IFormFile> files... Also the name of the parameter has to be the same as the field in form.

Comment: I have done this many times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the request body with dot pattern like this:

[image]

Then you need to add [FromForm] attribute to the controller input parameter.
Also note that the variable names in the postman and controller must match.

```cs
[HttpPost("post-images")]
public async Task<IList<RepositoryItem>> PostAnImages ([FromForm]IList<PostRepoRequest> repositoryItems)
```

With these changes, you will be able to get the request correctly:

[image]

Comment: thanks for example I will check it now ! What was wrong with me implementation where I used to receive List of PostRepoRequestDTO ? instead of only one PostRepoRequestDTO ?

Comment: this example really works but how come? Why did you convert `List<PostRepoRequest>` request to `PostRepoRequestDTO request`.. what was wrong with `List<PostRepoRequest> request` ? Wouldnt be nicer if we received few objects with those properties? instead of this arrays? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Roxy'Pro you are right, no need to change request object, I updated the answer with a shorter a nicer way. Can you try please? All you need to change in code is adding [FromForm] as I indicated in the updated answer.

Comment: now when I've changed it to   `[FromForm] List<PostRepoRequest> request `, now I can't receive data from postman :( Could you try also please?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro the input name on the controller and postman must match. Both of them must be same. Please try like this `([FromForm]IList<PostRepoRequest> repositoryItems)`, I updated it in the answer now.

Comment: I remember the code you posted earlier you used for loop to loop selected files from postman, and I'm wondering is it better to use for or foreach in this case? :) Thanks for helppp

Comment: @Roxy'Pro it won't make much difference. And with the updated answer we don't need a loop, right?

Comment: True we don't need

Answer (score 1):

Try to send file as separated parameter

```
[HttpPost("post-images")]
public async Task<IList<RepositoryItem>> PostAnImages (IList<PostRepoRequest> request, [FromForm]List<IFormFile> files)
{
    // rest of the code 
}
```

and in client (assuming that can be Angular):

```
let input = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++) {
   input.append("files", this.filesToUpload[i]);
}
```

Comment: Good point but I need it as part of a list because I would like to send list of the files to web api...

Answer (score 0):

There is an invisible selectbox, just move your cursor to left and you'll see the selectable area. Then select it as a file.

[image]

And add `[FromBody]` at he beginnig of ypur method parameter like `([FromBody]IList<PostRepoRequest> request)`

And last, update the `Key` to `...[0][file]` (you've forgot [])

Comment: it's allready a file, how otherwise I could select a file from computer :)

Comment: thanks for noticing that, I've tried that earlier also